# Peek and Pop 3D Touch - non-rectangular previewingContext presentation

Tags: ios, calayer, 3dtouch

During the indication hint of the peeking and popping (that moment when the view that gets pressed remains sharp while all else begins to blur), I want the area that remains sharp to be non-rectangular... trapezoidal, to be precise. How to accomplish this?

In implementing 3D Touch, we all know that we set the sourceRect property of the previewingContext in the method

```
- (UIViewController *)previewingContext:(id<UIViewControllerPreviewing>)previewingContext viewControllerForLocation:(CGPoint)location
```

Mine looks something like this:

```
- (UIViewController *)previewingContext:(id<UIViewControllerPreviewing>)previewingContext viewControllerForLocation:(CGPoint)location {

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.particularView.frame, location)) {

        previewingContext.sourceRect = self.particularView.frame;

        MyCustomViewController *customVC = [[MyCustomViewController customInit];
        customVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;
        customVC.preferredContentSize = self.view.frame.size;

        return customVC;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Everything works, totally as imagined. But I don't want the whole square of previewingContext.sourceRect to remain sharp! I want to cut off a corner, leaving a trapezoid sharp. Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Have you figured this out?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
customVC.view.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
```